# How to add hyperlink to another controller ruby on rail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to add the hyperlink of omdpratice into OdPratice's index.erb file so that when the admins open the OdPractice, they will be able to click the hyperlink and switch to omdpratice controller (omd endpoints). I have tried to lots of research and i am not able to find it . Can somebody point out the mistake or give me a resource how everything work ?

```
OdPractices.ruby

class Admin::OdPracticesController < Admin::AdminParentController

  def index
    authorize(OdPractice)
      @od_practices = policy_scope(OdPractice).kept.order(name: :asc).all
      @od_practices_suspended = policy_scope(OdPractice).discarded.order(name: :asc).all
     
  end
end

OmdPractices.ruby

class Admin::OmdPracticesController < Admin::AdminParentController
  include Paymenty # for create vaulted shopper
  include Banky


  def index
    authorize(OmdPractice)
    @omd_practices = policy_scope(OmdPractice).kept.all
    @omd_practices_suspended = policy_scope(OmdPractice).discarded.all
  end
end

index.erb of OdPraticeController

 <% @od_practices.each do |od_practice| %>
      <tr class='a-filterable-row'>
        <td>
          <%= link_to od_practice.name, admin_od_practice_path(od_practice) %>
         //Not working 
         <%= link_to omd_pratice.name, admin_omd_practice_path(@omd_pratice) %>

        </td>
        <td class="text-center"><%= od_practice.referring_ods.kept.count %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you're fetching OmdPractices records in Admin::OdPracticesController#index. Try this.

```
OdPractices.ruby

class Admin::OdPracticesController < Admin::AdminParentController

  def index
    authorize(OdPractice)
      @omd_practices = OmdPractice.all
      @od_practices = policy_scope(OdPractice).kept.order(name: :asc).all
      @od_practices_suspended = policy_scope(OdPractice).discarded.order(name: :asc).all
     
  end
end
        index.erb of OdPraticeController
    
     <% @od_practices.each do |od_practice| %>
          <tr class='a-filterable-row'>
            <td>
             <%= link_to od_practice.name, admin_od_practice_path(od_practice) %>
             // try fetching equivalent records by something like this. Not sure of your association method
             <% omd_practice = @omd_practices.find_by(od_practice_id: od_practice.id) %>
             <%= link_to omd_pratice.name, admin_omd_practice_path(omd_pratice) %>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center"><%= od_practice.referring_ods.kept.count %></td>
    <% end %>
```